# replace yaml array with json format using bash, yq, jq

Tags: yaml, yq

For readability purpose when displaying informations using yaml format, I'd like to be able to replace a yaml array with its json equivalent
The thing is that I may have several instances to replace in the yaml file/output with different paths

Example:

```
objects:
  - object:
      name: objA
      inputs:
        - dims:
          - 1
          - 3
  - object:
      name: objB
      outputs:
        - dims:
          - 5
```

but I'd like the output to be json format for dims arrays, like

```
objects:
  - object:
      name: objA
      inputs:
        - dims: [1,3]
  - object:
      name: objB
      outputs:
        - dims: [5]
```

converting the value from yaml to json is easy, modifying the value of the yaml nodes is easy, but I don't see how I can get the value for a "dims" node, convert it to a json value string, a put it back in the node (I mean without searching explicitly all instances)

in general, I'm looking for a way to replace the value of a node, with the result of a process on the value of the node (other example, replacing an id with the name of the corresponding object retrieved through a REST api request)

```
objects:
  - object:
      name: objA
      dependency: 3fc4bd5b-a6ee-4469-946d-5f780476784e
```

would be displayed as

```
objects:
  - object:
      name: objA
      dependency: name-of-dependency
```

where the id is replaced by the friendly name of the dependency

thanks

Comment: Which yq version are you using? the Go mikefarah or the Python version? Please state that on your question

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info for the various yq implementation details

Comment: AFAIK, yq does not support translation from YAML to JSON for a particular record alone. It supports for the whole file though. If you think its useful, you should raise a feature request - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues

Comment: I'm using the Go implemented version from mikefarah, but I'm not stuck to it (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mikefarah's yq

```
yq e '.objects[].object["inputs","outputs"][].dims? |= "["+join(",")+"]"' data.yml
```

Comment: @Inian If you look at OP's comment in the other answer, that's exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: thanks, it's exactly what I need

Comment: looking for the documentation more deeply, I finally found the following solution:

`yq '.objects[].object["inputs","outputs"][].dims? |= to_json(0)' sample.yaml`

or even shorter

`yq '.objects[].object["inputs","outputs"][].dims? |= @json()' sample.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tojson` and the update operator `|=`. This will encode your arrays as JSON, which is a string and therefore itself enclosed in quotes:

```sh
yq -y '(.. | .dims? | arrays) |= tojson'
```

```
objects:
  - object:
      name: objA
      inputs:
        - dims: '[1,3]'
  - object:
      name: objB
      outputs:
        - dims: '[5]'
```

<sub>Run with [Python yq](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/)</sub>

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for
only little drawback, I have to change my yq command to use the kislyuk version instead of the mikefarah I'm currently using